# If leaving a ModelForm BooleanField unchecked returns no POST data, how do I have my view do one thing if it's checked and another if it isn't?

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    breakfast = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    dinner = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    training = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And a view:

```
def cust_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustForm(request.POST)
        form_type = 'Customer'
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            name = request.POST['name']
            if request.POST['training'] == True:
                mail.mailsend(name, email, cus_type='train')
            else:
                mail.mailsend(name, email, cus_type='stand')
            form.save()
            return Redirect('/cr/')
        return render_to_response('cust_form.html', 
                 {'form': form,
                  'form_type': form_type},
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I want to send one email if they've opted for training, and one if they have not.  However, if the radio box is left unchecked, I get a `MultiValueDictKeyError at /Customer/`

Is the only solution to this a ForeignKey with yes/no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check that the value is there.

```
if 'training' in request.POST:
```

or

```
if request.POST.get('training'):
```

(You shouldn't compare against True, anyway.)

Comment: I tried `False` too!  I used your first example, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

change the line to

```
 if request.POST.get('training', False):
```